# Relating change of variables formula in in probability to the version in calculus

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, measure-theory, statistics

I am trying to relate the transformation of a random variable to the change of variables formula.

Firstly, the setup of the transformation of a random variable is as follows from Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger:

> Suppose $(X,Y)$ is a bi-variate random vector with known probability distribution. Consider the new bi-variate random vector $(U,V)$ defined by $U=g_1(X,Y)$ and $V=g_2(X,Y)$. Where $g_1(x,y)$ and $g_2(x,y)$ are some specified functions. If $B$ is any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $(U,V)\in B$ if and only if $(X,Y)\in A$ where $A=\{(x,y):(g_1(x,y),g_2(x,y)\in B\}$. Thus $P((U,V)\in B)=P((X,Y)\in A)$, and the probability distribution of $(U,V)$ is completely determined by the probability distribution of $(X,Y)$.
>
> If $(X, Y)$ is a continuous random vector with joint $\operatorname{pdf} f_{X, Y}(x, y)$, then the joint pdf of $(U, V)$ can be expressed in terms of $f_{X, Y}(x, y)$ in a manner analogous to (2.1.8). As before, $\mathcal{A}=\left\{(x, y): f_{X, Y}(x, y)>0\right\}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\left\{(u, v): u=g_{1}(x, y)\right.$ and $v=g_{2}(x, y)$ for some $(x, y) \in \mathcal{A}\}$. The joint $\operatorname{pdf} f_{U, V}(u, v)$ will be positive on the set $\mathcal{B}$. For the simplest version of this result we assume that the transformation $u=g_{1}(x, y)$ and $v=g_{2}(x, y)$ defines a one-to-one transformation of $\mathcal{A}$ onto $\mathcal{B}$. The transformation is onto because of the definition of $\mathcal{B}$. We are assuming that for each $(u, v) \in \mathcal{B}$ there is only one $(x, y) \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $(u, v)=\left(g_{1}(x, y), g_{2}(x, y)\right)$. For such a one-to-one, onto transformation, we can solve the equations $u=g_{1}(x, y)$ and $v=g_{2}(x, y)$ for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. We will denote this inverse transformation by $x=h_{1}(u, v)$ and $y=h_{2}(u, v)$. The role played by a derivative in the univariate case is now played by, a quantity called the Jacobian of the transformation. This function of $(u, v)$, denoted by $J$, is the determinant of a matrix of partial derivatives. It is defined by
> $$
> J=\left|\begin{array}{ll}
> \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
> \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
> \end{array}\right|=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}
> $$
> where
> $$
> \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial h_{1}(u, v)}{\partial u}, \quad \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial h_{1}(u, v)}{\partial v}, \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial h_{2}(u, v)}{\partial u}, \quad \text { and } \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial h_{2}(u, v)}{\partial v} .
> $$
> We assume that $J$ is not identically $0$ on $\mathcal{B}$. Then the joint pdf of $(U, V)$ is 0 outside the set $\mathcal{B}$ and on the set $\mathcal{B}$ is given by
> $$
> f_{U, V}(u, v)=f_{\boldsymbol{X}, Y}\left(h_{1}(u, v), h_{2}(u, v)\right)|J|
> $$

Now, in Folland's Real Analysis, we have the following result

> 2.47 Theorem. Suppose that $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $G: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a $C^{1}$ diffeomorphism.
> a. If $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on $G(\Omega)$, then $f \circ G$ is Lebesgue measurable on $\Omega$. If $f \geq 0$ or $f \in L^{1}(G(\Omega), m)$, then
> $$
> \int_{G(\Omega)} f(x) d x=\int_{\Omega} f \circ G(x)\left|\operatorname{det} D_{x} G\right| d x
> $$
> b. If $E \subset \Omega$ and $E \in \mathcal{L}^{n}$, then $G(E) \in \mathcal{L}^{n}$ and $m(G(E))=\int_{E}\left|\operatorname{det} D_{x} G\right| d x$.

I am trying to relate the Casella theorem to the Folland theorem. In this case, would $f=(X,Y)$ the random variable and $G(x,y)=(g_1(x,y),g_2(x,y))$ the transformation? What strikes me as odd is why the random variable would have to be defined on $G(\Omega)$. Wouldn't the random variable have to be defined on $\Omega$ and the transformation defined on its range?